# How to find out first occurrence of each phase

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am working on customer data where customer phase can change based on different factors. I need to find out every phase and the time it was changed to that phase.

Sample Data:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

I tried to use Lag function but it is repeating.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lag` can help here, but you need to add some filtering and deal with `null` in lag result

```sql
with ordered_data as (
    select *
         , lag(phase) over (order by phase_date desc) prev_phase
         , lag(phase_date) over (order by phase_date desc) prev_phase_date
    from monitoring.st1
)
select *
from ordered_data
where phase != prev_phase

union

(
    select *
         , phase as prev_phase
         , phase_date as prev_phase_date
    from monitoring.st1
    order by phase_date
    limit 1
)
order by phase_date desc
```

it generates the following result, where **prev_phase** and **prev_phase_date** hold result which you're looking for

| customerid | phase | phase_date | prev_phase | prev_phase_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Hold | 2021-07-08 | Active | 2021-08-08 |
| A | Suspended | 2020-11-10 | Hold | 2021-01-01 |
| A | Active | 2020-10-01 | Suspended | 2020-11-10 |
| A | Hold | 2020-08-08 | Active | 2020-10-01 |
| A | Active | 2020-03-06 | Hold | 2020-05-05 |
| A | Active | 2020-01-01 | Active | 2020-01-01 |

Comment: Thank you, worked as expected.